# "A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations." with regards to variables in SP

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

My query is much more complex than I'll post here, but I'm unable to use a variable while using an `sp_execute` SQL ... is there a workaround?

```
declare @system_status varchar(30)
select @system_status = '12,20'

declare @sql nvarchar(4000)

select @sql = 'SELECT [system_status] 
FROM VW_Document_Main 
WHERE 1=1 ' 

IF @system_status IS NOT NULL AND @system_status NOT IN ('-1','0') 
BEGIN 
SELECT @sql = @sql + 'and (',''+@system_Status+'',') LIKE ''%,''+system_Status+'',%'''
```

I'm attempting to concatenate a string onto the end of the SQL and eventually query it by using `sp_executesql`

However, I get an error message with regards to my concatenation :

> *A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be
>   combined with data-retrieval operations.*

Any ideas on how to fix it / work around??

.... Well that's embarrassing, SET in place of SELECT worked fine...

Comment: You tagged this MySQL but that syntax looks like SQL Server, can you confirm the database you are using?

Comment: @bluefeet It has to be `SQL Server` due to the `nvarchar`

Comment: sorry about that, it is SQL Server

Comment: Just try by using `SET` instead of `SELECT`...

Comment: @PolishPrince I agree, just want to confirm though. :)

Comment: I don't think you included all of the code, and I suspect the second `SELECT` goes on to do more things (e.g. selecting from a table). The error message is pretty self-explanatory but we can't help you fix your code if you don't show us all of the code.

Answer (score 1):

You are having a problem with the commas in your SELECT.  I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do so here are two possible ways I've gotten it working.

1) Remove the commas.

```
SELECT @sql = @sql + 'and ('''+@system_Status+''') LIKE ''%,''+system_Status+'',%'''
```

This makes the query look like this.

```
SELECT [system_status] 
FROM VW_Document_Main 
WHERE 1=1 and ('12,20') LIKE '%,'+system_Status+',%'
```

2) Add more quotes so that the commas aren't outside the strings.

```
SELECT @sql = @sql + 'and ('',''+@system_Status+'','') LIKE ''%,''+system_Status+'',%'''
```

Which makes the output like this.

```
SELECT [system_status] 
FROM VW_Document_Main 
WHERE 1=1 and (','+@system_Status+',') LIKE '%,'+system_Status+',%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dynamic sql construnction has error. I think what you need in your last line is like this:

```
SELECT @sql = @sql + 
              'and ('+','+@system_Status+',) LIKE ''%,'+
              @system_Status+',%'''
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing some quote marks:

```
declare @system_status varchar(30)
select @system_status = '12,20'

declare @sql nvarchar(4000)

select @sql = 'SELECT [system_status] 
FROM VW_Document_Main 
WHERE 1=1 ' 

IF @system_status IS NOT NULL AND @system_status NOT IN ('-1','0') 
BEGIN 
SELECT @sql = @sql + 'and ('','+@system_Status+','') LIKE ''%,''+system_Status+'',%'''
END
SELECT @sql
```